# Conditions based on multiple arrays in nested IF statements in Woocommerce

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

Basically I'm trying to get the second `IF` statement to work if the criteria of the first `If` statement is met.

The fisrt `IF` statement is meant to check against user roles and if it matches with "bba" or "duk", then then second `IF` statement will check for specific product ids that should not match avoiding a custom cart wide bulk discount.

I know the second `IF` statement works as it works by itself but it disables the bulk discount for all users instead of specific defined ones.

This is my code:

```
if ( in_array( 'bba', 'duk' (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    if( ! in_array($values['product_id'], array('493','387'))){
      $quantiy_total += $values['quantity'];  
      //$price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);

      $price = $values['line_subtotal'];

     // echo "####".$price."####";


      $cart_total += $price;
    }   

  }
  }
```

Or my second attempt that doesn’t work either:

```
if ( ! in_array($user['roles'], array('bba','duk'))){

    if( ! in_array($values['product_id'], array('493','387'))){
      $quantiy_total += $values['quantity'];  
      //$price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);

      $price = $values['line_subtotal'];

     // echo "####".$price."####";


      $cart_total += $price;
    }   

  }
  }
```

With both codes the bulk discount is disabled for product IDs 439 and 387 without  taking into account the First `IF` statement.

How can I make the First `IF` statement working and checking for the targeted user roles?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `IF` with 2 arrays you need to use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) instead of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

There is also some other mistakes. Try the following:

```
$cart = WC()->cart; // (If needed) The cart object

$total_quantity = $total_amount = 0; // Initializing variables

if ( array_intersect( array('bba','duk'),  $user['roles'] ) ) {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart-get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if ( ! in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), array('493','387') ) ) {
            // Cumulated total quantity of targeted cart items
            $total_quantity += $cart_item['quantity'];

            // The product price
            // $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

            // The line item subtotal not discounted (product price x quantity)
            $subtotal_price = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];

            // The line item total discounted ( (product price x quantity) - coupon discount )
            // $total_price = $cart_item['line_total'];

            // Cumulated line subtotals amount of targeted cart items
            $subtotal_amount += $subtotal_price;
        }
    }
}

// Testing output
echo '<p>Total quantity is ' . $total_quantity . ' and Subtotal amount is ' . $subtotal_amount . '</p>';
```

It should better work now.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help! Unfortunately this is disabling the discount entirely but its given me a better understanding thank you!